# What will happen if I apply 220 dc voltage to a 220 ac load?

Tags: ac, dc

Let say I have a lamp which is operated on 220 V ac.

Instead of applying 220 AC voltage I apply 220 DC voltage: what will happen? And if I want to convert this 220V dc to 220V ac then what should I do?

Comment: what kind of lamp is that? Simple incandescent or some other that needs driving circuitry?

Comment: Split up your second question about DC to AC conversion. Or better yet, search for that question asked already.

Comment: A lamp is fine.  An inductive load is something different

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An incandescent bulb will do fine. The 220 V AC is the RMS value, for Root Mean Square. The sine's amplitude will be \$\sqrt{2}\$ higher than that, or 310 V. But the RMS value tells you what equivalent DC voltage you would need to get the same power, so that's exactly what you need. The bulb will use the same power and light as bright under 220 V AC as DC.

Switching on an incandescent bulb may cause a large current peak: the cold resistance is only about a tenth of what it is when the lamp is lit, and when the voltage applied is high at that time the lamp may break. You may have noticed that *if* a bulb breaks it always does when switching on. So at AC worst case is when you switch on at the peak of the sine, at 310 V. But there will be lots of cases when the voltage is lower when switching on, even zero if you just happen to switch on during a zero-crossing of the sine. In fact that's the best thing to do for the bulb's longevity.

At DC you don't have this; anytime you switch it on it will be 220 V. Not as bad as 310 V, but you can't use zero-crossing switching either.

**about RMS**
Why do we use RMS value instead of just the average? The average of a sine is just zero, so that doesn't help at all. If we want to know how much power a voltage generates in a load we have to use the power equation

\$ P = V \times I = \dfrac{V^2}{R} \$

It's the second form we're interested in. Power is proportional to voltage squared, that's what the "S" in RMS comes from, we square the voltage.

[image]

The blue sine is our AC voltage, 1 V peak. The purple curve is that voltage squared, and the yellowish is the average of that, or mean: the "M" in RMS. It's precisely 0.5 V\$^2\$. It has still the dimension of voltage squared, so to get to a voltage quantity we take the square root of that, that's \$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\$ V. The "R" in RMS. So RMS spelled out in full means: "the square root of the average of the voltage squared".

This shows that the amplitude (1 V) is \$\sqrt{2}\$ higher than the RMS value. That's where the 310 V comes from: 220 V \$\times \sqrt{2}\$ = 310 V.

Comment: so what you mean is it will work. 
will there be any harm on lamp or if i say it is not lamp it is some kind of circuitry?

Comment: @Rizwan - No, there won't be a damage to the lamp. It will not work for many other loads, depending on the kind of load, but the bulb is resistive, and the answer is valid for resistive loads.

Comment: Be aware that *switching* 220VDC is an entirely different matter than 220VAC.  Most home-grade switches are made to take advantage of the zero crossing in the AC waveform to quench the arc created by a disconnect event.  With DC, there is constant current flow, so alternate approaches to extinguishing the arc are required such as magnetic blowouts or vacuum contactors.

Comment: To the OP, for the last question: I'd just leave it be until you understand more than just the difference between AC and DC. I mean no offense, on the most neutral tone. (Net is playing tricks, this was supposed to end up as a comment to the 1st post, F5 took me here, sorry about that)

Answer (score 1):

YES your incandescent lamp will run on DC  in fact Thomas Edison who had a design contract to improve the reliability of the lightbulb and hence commercialise it did all his experiments on DC Thomas Edison wanted all power to be DC but lost to Nicholas Tesla NOW a word of warning    DC arcs much worse than AC so unless your switch is huge and 100years old then check its rating  Many 230Vac switches are only rated for 28 Vdc